# Listview results issues

Tags: c#, azure, xaml, xamarin.forms

hope this is my listview final issue and question here is my code

```
  public  List<CustomerEntity> CET1 { get; set; } = new List<CustomerEntity>();

    public async void MakeupBTN_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string storageConnectionString = "mystringconnection";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = DOTFORMS3.Common.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("mytablename");
        TableQuery<CustomerEntity> tableQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();
        foreach (CustomerEntity MyCustomerEntity in table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery))
        {
            CET1.Add(MyCustomerEntity);
        }
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new pagggge(CET1));
    }
```

and here is the code from pagggge

```
 public  List<CustomerEntity> MCET { get; set; } = new List<CustomerEntity>();
    public pagggge( List<CustomerEntity> cet)
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        cet = MCET;
        this.BindingContext = this;         

    }
```

and here is my xaml code

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MCET}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label  Text="{Binding PLACE}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding NAME}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding PRICE}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding TIME}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

and her is my customer class

```
  public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
{
    public CustomerEntity()
    {
    }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string PLACE { get; set; }
    public string PRICE { get; set; }
    public string TIME { get; set; }
}
```

nathing appears into my listview after all of that so where could possibly be the issue ?

Comment: `cet = MCET;` this sets the variable that gets passed to your constructor to your local property. My assumption would be you would want this the other way around.

Comment: yeah you are right , it should be ` MCET = cet ` . thx <3

Comment: write it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Done, good luck with your project!

Comment: thanks alot for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
cet = MCET;
```

should be

```
MCET = cet;
```

Answer (score 0):

`cet = MCET;`

this sets the variable that gets passed to your constructor to your local property. My assumption would be you would want this the other way around so change it to:

`MCET = cet;`.